# How do I use "cheat giveexptoplayer .."

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

Listed on [Steam Community](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=454529617):

> cheat giveexptoplayer `[id]` `[how much]` `[tribeshared]` `[preventsharing]`
>
> Gives experience to another player, use showmyadminmanager for the
>   required information. Unable to test currently.

`[id]` is presumably gained from `[showmyadminmanager]` but not sure what format `[tribeshared]` & `[preventsharing]` need to be in. It's likely a yes/no or 1/0 thing but want to make sure before I run it.

Comment: Try using admincheat instead of cheat. Some of the cheat commands use this syntax.

Comment: The issues isn't not being able to run it. I'm just looking for confirmation on the `tribeshared` and `preventsharing` parameter values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the admin manager, unless you know the player's ID.

I tend to go into console use ShowMyAdminManager to get the player's ID.  Then you can use the console command or the admin manager, depending what it wants.

So to give you an example of the admin manager, since that can be confusing for people.  When you double click GiveExpToPlayer (with the player highlighted in the list), just click Copy Player ID to get their ID, then put the rest in like 12345 150000 1 0 and hit Execute.  12345 is the Player ID, 150k is the exp, 1 is FromTribeShare, and 0 would share the exp with the tribe.  FromTribeShare doesn't make as much sense to me right now, but the description is to apply exp as if it came from the tribe.  I would suggest playing with that to figure out how it affects the exp.

So same thing with console, you can just put in cheat giveexptoplayer 12345 150000 1 0 and get the same result.  Also for the last 2, you can use true and false as well as 1 (true) and 0 (false).

Answer (score 1):

```
GiveExpToPlayer <PlayerID> <HowMuch> <FromTribeShare> <PreventSharingWithTribe>

PlayerID                     Integer[32]    Player's in-game UE4 ID

HowMuch                      Float          Amount to give

FromTribeShare               Boolean        Apply as if experience came from tribe

PreventSharingWithTribe      Boolean        Gives the specified player the specified amount of experience points

1: player only
0: share with tribe

Example: GiveExpToPlayer 0123456789 1000 0 1
Result:  Only that player with the specified ID gains 1000 experience.
```

: http://ark.gamepedia.com/Admin_Game_Commands